# What's the purpose of な in なのに?

Tags: grammar, particles, formal-nouns, particle-な

I don't understand the role of "な" when used before "のに" as in these two sentences (with given translations):

> 朝目がさめて初めて、外が雪**な**のに気がついた。

He noticed that there was snow outside only after he woke up in the morning.

> せっかくの日曜日**な**のに働いた。

Although Sunday is precious (to me), I worked (all day long).

I'm similarly confused by the なので pattern, but I assume the principle is the same there.
My best guesses so far are that:

1. There's some relation to な-adjectives, but I don't see how 雪 or 日曜日
   would be acting as adjectives here.
2. The な has essentially the same
   role as だ (i.e. a "copula"?), but you can't use だ in the middle of a
   sentence like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track. `の` is a formal noun with a general meaning such as `the case`, `the fact`, or `the situation`. The sequence `...な` is an appositive clause modifying the formal noun `の`.

> 彼は学生だ
>   'He is a student.'
>
> [彼は学生な]のだ
>   'It is the case [that he is a student].'
>   The appositive clause `彼は学生な` 'that he is a student' modifies the formal noun `の` 'the case'.

As you suspect, `な` is the form of copula that is used exclusively when it is used in a clause that modifies a noun (i.e., relative clause or appositive clause).

> 彼は静かだ
>   'He is quiet.'
>
> [静かな]人
>   'person [who is quiet]'  (relative clause with na-adjective as a predicate)

Na-adjectives are actually very close to nouns, and depending on the theoretical framework, they can be actually considered a subclass of noun. You can usually observe this `な` form used together with na-adjevtives, but with nouns, you don't usually see it except for a number of fixed expressions like the one you see here because with nouns, you have the option of using the genitive case particle `の`, and that is preferred.

> 彼は学生だ
>   'He is a student.'
>
> × [学生な]人
>   'person [who is a student]' (relative clause with a noun as a predicate; usually considered ungrammatical to use `な`)
>
> 学生の人
>   (Uses genitive case particle)

Answer (score 2):

First, the two のに are completely different.

> 外が雪なのに気がついた。

そとが+雪+な+の+に気づく

の is used to make a noun of the preceding proposition, so as to make the proposition the object of 気づく (object indicated by に).
But then, a proposition cannot end with a noun, it must end with a verb, and 雪 is not a verb.
The proposition is in fact そとが雪だ。
And when you put だ in determinant form (so that it determines の) you turn it into な.
That's it.
To realise [the fact that [outside is snow]]

> 日曜日なのに働いた。

This is a "grief" のに, and also goes with a proposition, not a noun.
Your proposition is 日曜日だ. You turn だ into な, and you can now stick のに behind it.

So, your point 1 is wrong.
Your point 2 is right, and turning だ into な is a solution.

なので will work similarly, and be like the second example (since ので and the second のに are single grammatical particles).

Comment: That would explain why I had been somewhat confused in general by the first sentence.  It makes much more sense when you split up the の and the に like that.  I guess I didn't realize there was a non-grief のに.